# Nativescript Layout

Tags: nativescript

Hi I'm trying to play with layouts in nativescript. I was looking at listviews, and I tried this in the playground using the code from the docs (https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/list-view#using-multiple-item-templates).

However, I can't get the listview to display (Playground : https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=nhm5el&v=7). I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly for the listview not to be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy/paste error - you have copied the code for your ListView component but at the same time your `HomeComponent` is empty (and this is where the list view items should be initialized with your `DataSerice`) - demo [here](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=nhm5el&v=8). I would advise against handling multiple components and services in a single file and as a good practice always separate the different components and services in their own files - this way similar error will be much more easier to catch.

Comment: oh great thanks Nick. I added them into the same file just to try it out but agree that they needed to be separated.